# need help to write a recursive function to draw tree structure

Tags: laravel, recursion, laravel-blade

I am drawing a tree structure using blade template but I want to write it for any level of child. I think this can be achieved using recursion. Here is the code

```
<div class="tree">

  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">{{ $root->first_name }} {{ $root->last_name }}</a>
      @if($root->children->count())
      <ul>
        @foreach($root->children as $childlevel1)
        <li>
          <a href="#">{{ $childlevel1->first_name }} {{ $childlevel1->last_name }}</a>
            @if($childlevel1->children->count())
            <ul>
              @foreach($childlevel1->children as $childlevel2)
              <li>
                <a href="#">{{ $childlevel2->first_name }} {{ $childlevel2->last_name }}</a>
                @if($childlevel2->children->count())
                <ul>
                  @foreach($childlevel2->children as $childlevel3)
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">{{ $childlevel3->first_name }} {{ $childlevel3->last_name }}</a>
                  </li>       
                  @endforeach
                </ul>
                @endif
              </li>       
              @endforeach
            </ul>
            @endif
        </li>       
        @endforeach
      </ul>
       @endif
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve above problem. I created a partial blade template parentchild.blade.php and added the code below :

```
@if($parent->children->count())
<ul>
  @foreach($parent->children as $child)
  <li>
    <a href="#">{{ $child->first_name }} {{ $child->last_name }}</a>
    @include('parentchild',['parent' => $child])
  </li>       
  @endforeach
</ul>
@endif
```

And then I included the above partial template in main template like this:

```
<div class="tree">

  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">{{ $root->first_name }} {{ $root->last_name }}</a>
        @include('parentchild', ['parent' => $root] )
    </li>
  </ul>
```

So, finally its working :)